# Page Number on crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to display the page number on my crystal report only if the number of pages is more than 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag and drop the special field page number on to report and write a supress condition

If total page count > 1
Then false
Else true

Here total page count is again a special field